# Converting height map bitmap to json

Tags: json, f#

This is my first F# program.

It's a command line utility that takes a parameter containing a path to an height map bitmap and prints out this height map converted to JSON format.

```
open System.Drawing

let convertLine (y:int) (bitmap:System.Drawing.Bitmap) =
    [ for x in 0 .. bitmap.Width - 1 -> "\"" + bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).R.ToString() + "\"" ] |> String.concat ", "

let convert (path:string) : string = 
    let bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path)
    let results = [ for y in 0 .. bitmap.Height - 1 -> convertLine y bitmap ] |> String.concat ", "

    "{\"X\": \"" + bitmap.Width.ToString() + 
    "\", \"Y\": \"" + bitmap.Width.ToString() + 
    "\", \"values\":[" + results + "]}"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let arglist = argv |> List.ofSeq

    let returnValue = 
        match arglist with
            | path :: _ -> convert path
            | _ -> "Wrong number of arguments supplied"

    printfn "%s" returnValue

    match returnValue with
        | "Wrong number of arguments supplied" -> 1
        | _ -> 0
```

I want to make sure to write idiomatic F# and to write in a functional style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would make some changes:

```
let returnValue = 
    match arglist with
        | path :: _ -> convert path
        | _ -> "Wrong number of arguments supplied"
```

should probably be something like

```
let returnValue = 
    match arglist with
        | path :: _ -> convert path
        | _ ->failwith "Wrong number of arguments supplied"
```

which would simplify some logic

I would also change the printing to use sprintf

```
"{\"X\": \"" + bitmap.Width.ToString() + 
"\", \"Y\": \"" + bitmap.Width.ToString() + 
"\", \"values\":[" + results + "]}"
```

becomes

```
sprintf "{\"X\": \"%i\", \"Y\": \"%i\", \"values\":[%s]}" (bitmap.Width.ToString() ) (bitmap.Width.ToString() ) results
```

Comment: Will failtwith return an error (>0) from the command line?

Comment: Probably - if you want to be paranoid you can use a try catch which is still much nicer that your initial approach